# Is this sentences correct "It seems like the output of some process may not be useful stand-alone"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

I am writing a scientific article.

I want to say: "The output of some process may not be useful in itself (or on its own), but it is an important preprocessing step to later stage processes."

Can I use *"stand-alone"* instead of *"in itself"* or *"on its own"* in the above sentence?

I know that "*stand-alone*" is an adjective, and it may not be correct to use it at end of a sentence. However, I am looking for something that is more natural.

Your help would be highly appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: _In itself_ seems perfectly natural to me.

Comment: Aha, thank you. Maybe I am lost in some details here.

Answer (score 1):

As you have identified, "stand-alone" is an adjective and is not correct at the end of the sentence. It needs to have a noun to go with it.

You could try something like: "It seems like the output may not be useful **as a** stand-alone **product**". (I don't know what the output is so I'm not sure if product is the right noun here. You can substitute 'product' for whatever is most appropriate.)